# Why are the first N characters improperly decrypted using JCE?

Tags: java, encryption, jce

When I decrypt a message there is a constant number of characters that are not decrypted properly.  For example:

Before Decryption:{"header":{"messageId":"ca18d015-9861-47b8-9e09-81fb561522e5"

After Decryption: M��s����g�{�T\ageId":"ca18d015-9861-47b8-9e09-81fb561522e5"

I am initializing JCE with the following code:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
        .getInstance(KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(new String(dataKey).toCharArray(), SALT,
                                                          PBKDF_DEFAULT_ITERATIONS, 128));

    Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), KEY_TYPE);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector));
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes());
```

Comment: Is your payload correct?

Comment: Looks like your IV is wrong. Please show a full encryption/decryption cycle.

Comment: @ArtjomB. You are correct, it was my initialization vector.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization Vector was different when encrypting/decrypting.